# V-model property is updated only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have two checkboxes. Their values must be equal to watched computed properties. I can see reactive changes in my Vue extension if those properties were changed but I can see new checkbox states only after page refreshing. How can I update my component if watched computed property was changed?

Here is what I have in the template:

```
...
<input type="checkbox" v-model="emailSending">
<span class="ml-10 checkbox-label">Email</span>
<input type="checkbox" v-model="phoneSending">
<span class="ml-10 checkbox-label">Sms</span>
...
<script>
data() {
    return {
      emailSending: true,
      phoneSending: true,
    };
},
watch: {
    playerEmailSending(value) {
      this.emailSending = value;
    },
    playerPhoneSending(value) {
      this.phoneSending = value;
    },
},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getPlayerNotifications', 'getPlayer']),
    playerEmailSending() {
      return this.getPlayer.data.emailSending;
    },
    playerPhoneSending() {
      return this.getPlayer.data.phoneSending;
    },
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['loadPlayerNotifications']),
    save() {
      this.loadPlayerNotifications({
        emailSending: this.emailSending,
        phoneSending: this.phoneSending,
      });
    },
},
</script>
```

UPDATE:
As this page with checkboxes is a child of another page, here is what I have in my parent page:

```
...
// call an action which will fetch data about the player. 
// This data I will get with `getPlayer` getter in my child page.
created() {
    this.loadPlayer();
  },
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['loadPlayer']),
},
...
```

Comment: can you show the mutator part of vuex where you set `this.getPlayer.data.emailSending` and `this.getPlayer.data.phoneSending`? I suspect you may not be using `vue.set` method

Comment: As this template with checkboxes is a child of a page, I put the action via `mapActions` on the parent level. I call this action in `created` hook in a page template and then get only needed data in the child component with `getPlayer` getter.

Comment: @OlgaB I thought the issue might lie in the fact that you're computing nested object properties, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I tried to recreate your issue without using Vuex [here](http://jsfiddle.net/023mayLc/1/), but couldn't get the same issue. Perhaps add some of your Vuex code as Daniel suggested above.

Comment: Updated the issue. Can it be the fact that it is not direct nested component but a page the route of which is the child of another page?

Comment: @OlgaB I think your issue might be because of the fact that Vue can't detect property addition or deletion ([documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)). What do you set the initial value of the data you get from `getPlayer` as?

Comment: @DelenaMalan `getPlayer` returns a state with player's data object. `playerEmailSending` and `playerPhoneSending ` retrieve two values from this object respectively. Both of them are boolean.

Comment: Tried to reproduce your issue using Vuex [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8vguLbcn/3/) sticking as close as possible what you described your setup was, but couldn't. Would be useful if you could add a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your issue.

Comment: I think I solved this issue but cannot explain why it works this way. I will add my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by removing an action from a parent page and placing it in the component's `created` hook. I also assign my data properties to getter's values in this hook.

```
created() {
    this.loadPlayer();
    this.emailSending = this.playerEmailSending; // getter's value
    this.phoneSending = this.playerPhoneSending; // getter's value
  },
```